# How to calculate the energy used by a sound wave emitter if I know the frequency, Amplitude, decibel level and for how long the wave is emitted?

Tags: waves, energy-conservation, acoustics, potential-energy

The idea is I want to calculate the energy lost by a break (theoretically) while trying to stop a disk.
I have worked put the energy loss due to heat and light however I am not able to pin down on the energy lost by sound.
Assume the environment as ideal for simple calculations if needed. Any and all suggestions are welcome.
May seem like a silly question but even a simple formula would really help me.

PARAMETERS:

- Constant frequency $f$
- Density of air $\rho$
- Amplitude of sound wave (constant) $A$
- Time for which the wave is emitted taken as $T$

p.s. Just clarifying, I want to calculate for mechanical waves and I don't know what to take as $\mu$ value for air.